# error page not displayed as expected when navigating from ErrorHandler

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and i was trying to implement the error handler for the web page i am developing. I am having issue with displaying error page when navigating to it from Error handler

When i navigate to error page from error handler , the interpolation expressions in html is always undefined and not showing up the error being set.

In the error component (below code)  globals.errmsg value is getting logged in the constructor. but html does not display the value.

html does not display it. it looks like hte value is not getting passed to html at all.

Please find the code below

ReservationNotificationModule.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { appRoutes } from './route';
import { Globals } from './Shared/Globals';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';



import { RestService } from './Shared/Rest.Service';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpErrorInterceptor } from './Shared/HttpErrorInterceptor';
import { GlobalErrorHandler } from './Shared/GlobalErrorHandler';
import { NotificationHomeComponent } from './Notification/NotificationHome-component';
import { NotificationErrorComponent } from './Notification/NotificationError-component';

export const httpInterceptorProviders = [
  { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpErrorInterceptor, multi: true },
];


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NotificationAppComponent,
    NotificationHomeComponent,
    NotificationErrorComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    HttpClientModule,
    CommonModule
  ],
  providers: [Globals, Header, RestService, { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: GlobalErrorHandler }, httpInterceptorProviders],
  bootstrap: [NotificationHomeComponent]
})
export class ReservationNotificationModule {

}
```

Notification Home Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'notification-home',
  template: ` <div class="row"> some html</div>`

})
export class NotificationHomeComponent {

  constructor() {
    throw ("error");
  }
}
```

Globals.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Globals {
  culture: string;
  errormsg: string;
}
```

GlobalErrorHandler

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Globals } from './Globals'

@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) { }
  handleError(error) {
    console.log(error);
    const globals = this.injector.get(Globals);
    globals.errormsg = "Sorry we ran into a problem. Try again later";
    const router = this.injector.get(Router);

    console.log("Inside Global Error Handler");
    router.navigate(['/error']);
  }
}
```

ErrorComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Globals } from '../Shared/Globals'

@Component({
  selector: 'notification-error',
  template: `Error :  {{globals.errormsg}}`
})
export class NotificationErrorComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public globals: Globals) {
    console.log(globals.errormsg)
  };

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

Angular dependencies in my project

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.2.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "mustache": "^2.3.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  }
```

Edit : I noticed that when i did a prod build the error handler component worked as expected. I am seeing this behavior only in dev build. if anyone encounter this issue please try doing a prod build and see if it is getting resolved.

Comment: I looked into this a little bit and discovered that the same behaviour can be observed even if you remove `Globals` from the mix. Simply navigating to a component in the `ErrorHandler` and trying to set a value from said component in the HTML does not work. I mention this because you can simplify your code above greatly for the purpose of trying to get an answer.

Comment: Thanks Kirk. I found that the error component is working as expected in prod build. add it to my post so that it might help others.